# Using Angular $resource, Update List of Objects After Post Request

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, when using $resource, how do you update a list of objects after making a post request? If you save or update an individual object, you'd then want the the full list to reflect the change of data. Is this handled by $resource or do you have to implement this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do it after the update succeeds. how you do it it depends on your service return value and your approach

using the callback approach

## SOME CODE

```
  var R=$resource('searches/:id',null,{
      'update': { method:'PUT' }
  });

  R.delete({id:id},function(){
         $scope.searches.splice(searchIdxById(id),1);
         $scope.saved=false;
   });

  R.update({id:id},{},function(){
           //success
   },function(){
          //fails
    });
```

some reading
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of any codes examples so I can get a sense of how to do that?